# Do API Hooks Affect All Processes?

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

Say one hooks a given DLL's function.
Are all processes that make use of that specific function of that specific DLL affected by the hooking?

For example if one was to hook `MessageBoxA` from `user32.dll` so that instead of popping a MessageBox it would play Beatles' *Yellow Submarine* as a system sound. Would all processes calling `MessageBoxA` experience this rather strange behavior?

-João Silva

Comment: Thankfully, no.  Hard to keep an operating system running if that would work.

Comment: @HansPassant, I know this is an old question but I have a concern. I am working on a project where we are required to monitor  all system calls to a certain function "recv" regardless of the process that instantiated it. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking it would process specific.

When you load a DLL windows loads the dll into your memory space. If the the dll is already loaded into memory (and mapped into some process' space)  then windows will just map the memory into your process space.

However when you apply the hook, the memory is changed and thus windows will make a copy of said memory just for your process.

Read up on memory mapped files (the technology for this is what windows used to load code)

Comment: Um... well... not necessarily. Normally, text segments are `FILE_MAP_COPY`, so you're right, but this doesn't _need to be_ left that way.

Comment: @Damon - true there can always be exceptions. I was just stating the common approach. Please detail more in answer I'd like to read about it.

Comment: @Preet I asked this question because as far I thought I knew DLL's code is shared among processes. Are you saying that if a hook is applied to a user32.dll's function, the system will actually copy the whole DLL into the process memory space so its memory can be changed safely?

Comment: Dll Code is shared. But mapping is done at the 4k page level - so only the pages that are changed are 'reloaded' (well actually mapped on write) so it's very efficient.

Comment: Right. But those pages are duplicated then? The original DLL's memory is left unaltered?

Comment: yes. The DLL file is never touched. Only the loaded memory. In fact all .exes and .dll files are their own page files. Windows when needing to page out some memory that contains executable code will not bother putting it in the pagefile.sys - it will just loading again from the original dll code. Seriously read windows internals - it's great!

Comment: @JoãoSilva: This is what you call copy-on-write. The memory pages are the exact same (shared) as long as you only ever read them. Not so once you write to a page.